# Take His Vacation

Tags: determiners, parsing

I have a question about two very similar sentences:

> 1. He *took* ***an*** *annual vacation* to Canada.
> 2. He *took* ***his*** *annual vacation* to Canada.

How are the two sentences different?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 implies that he goes to Canada (almost) every year, during his annual vacation.  The sentence is about the entire series of vacations.

Sentence 2 is more ambiguous.  It could be parsed as:

2a) "He took his annual (vacation to Canada)", or as
 2b) "He took his (annual vacation) (to Canada)."

Interpretation 2a is similar to Sentence 1, except that it focuses on one particular vacation.

Interpretation 2b states that he takes a vacation (almost) every year.  It focuses on one particular vacation, during which he went to Canada.  It does not say how often he goes to Canada.  Two alternative sentences with this meaning are:

3. He vacationed in Canada this year.
4. This year, he went to Canada during his annual vacation.

Unfortunately, sentences 3 and 4 are also about as ambiguous as sentence 2.  Sentence 3 does not say whether he takes a vacation (almost) every year.  Sentence 4 does not say whether most of his vacation was in Canada, or if he just briefly visited Canada.